# How To Vlookup To Return Multiple Values In One Cell In Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

So I have the code that pastes multiple values into one cell but I was hoping to be able to put a semicolon in between the cell's value.

This code allows a vlookup to find multiple cell values and output them in one cell.

```
Function MYVLOOKUP(pValue As String, pWorkRng As Range, pIndex As Long)
'Update 20150310
Dim rng As Range
Dim xResult As String
xResult = ""
For Each rng In pWorkRng
    If rng = pValue Then
        xResult = xResult & ";" & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)
    End If
Next
MYVLOOKUP = xResult
End Function
```

When I do this it does put a semicolon in between the values like I want, but also has a billion semicolons after.

Comment: Can you put `Debug.Print rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)` before `xResult = xResult & ";" & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)` and see what that's returning?

Comment: If you have Office 365: `=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,IF(A1:A1000="MyValue",D1:D1000,""))` As an Array Formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter

Comment: @dwirony it still has a bunch of ; after

Comment: @scott craner where am I adding that?

Comment: it is a formula that you add on the sheet changing the ranges to the desired input and output, it is not vba

Comment: @PaigeHilliard Forget my first comment - what range are you selecting for `pWorkRng`? It must contain ALOT of blank cells.

Comment: try: `If rng = pValue And rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1) <> "" Then` for your If and `MYVLOOKUP = Left(xResult,Len(xResult)-1)`

Comment: @dwirony Good question. I'm not sure how OP's code *can* result in a bunch of blank items, other than `pValue` being `""`, or `On Error Resume Next` being specified (scrubbed for posting, I guess?) and `rng.Vaue` being e.g. `#N/A` for all these values. Below answer dodges that bullet though.

Answer (score 1):

I'd work with an array for this. Start by sizing it to fit the entire source:

```
Dim results As Variant
ReDim results(1 To pWorkRng.Count)
```

Then maintain a counter for the index of the last item in that array, and write at that index:

```
Dim currentIndex As Long

For Each rng In pWorkRng
    If Not IsError(rng.Value) Then
        If rng.Value = pValue Then
            currentIndex = currentIndex + 1
            results(currentIndex) = rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

When the loop completes, you'll have all the results up to `currentIndex`, and then a bunch of `Empty` values; truncate the array with `ReDim Preserve`:

```
ReDim Preserve results(1 To currentIndex)
```

And now you can return a string with all the results, using `String.Join`:

```
MYVLOOKUP = String.Join(results, ";")
```

Answer (score 0):

If Mathieu Guindons method doesn't work then, try to add the following to your code after the following line:

`xResult = xResult & ";" & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)`

```
    Do While (InStr(xResult, ";;") > 0)
        xResult = Replace(xResult, ";;", ";")
    Loop
```